# Awaiting manually created task is freezing ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, queue, task

I've made a queue, which contains tasks to do. After creating some tasks manually with `new Task()` in `Returns` method, my whole application hangs - `await current;`. The body of the task is not even triggered.

`ConfigureAwait(false)` didn't help.

The first task in the queue, which is not created by me, but other framework is executing successfully and returning a value. Mine - doesn't. I've tried add `Task.CompletedTask` and then it has worked. I don't understand why I can't even reach the body of the task containing `_output` assignment.

[IDE debugger code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhSCn.png)

---**UPDATE**---

The code works when I use code below. With `await` it doesn't. Any ideas?

```cs
current.Start();
current.Wait();
```

**Original code**

```
private readonly Queue<Task> _pipe;

public IPipeBuilder<TOutput> Returns(Func<IEnumerable<IExecutionResult>, TOutput> outputBuilder)
{
   _pipe.Enqueue(new Task(() => // this task causes a problem and breakpoint isn't hit inside 
   {
      _output = outputBuilder(_results);
   }));

   return this;
}

public async Task<TOutput> Execute()
{
   Task current;

   while (_pipe.TryDequeue(out current))
   {
      if (current.IsCommandExecution())
      {
         IExecutionResult result = await (Task<IExecutionResult>)current; // this awaits successfully
         _results.Add(result);
      }
      else
      {
         await current; // hangs here
      }
   }

   return await Task.FromResult(_output);
}
```

**Usage**

```
[HttpGet("eventflow/pipe/issue/add/{title}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PipeAction(string title)
   => Ok(
      await Pipe<IExecutionResult>()
           .Validate(title)
           .Handle<AddIssueCommand>(IssueId.New, title)
           .Returns(results => results.First())
           .Execute());
```

Comment: How are you calling `Execute` also why are you doing this `return await Task.FromResult(_output)` ? lastly, if you are pipelining tasks like this id potentialy look at *TPL DataFlow*, or *RX*

Comment: I've just updated the code with usage. And yeah, it's useless. I will change it to return `_output`

Comment: I think its time for a minimal reproducible example, pull out everything you can until the minimal set of code reproduces the problem, so we can test this in our environment

Comment: I am puzzled with the line `current.IsCommandExecution()`. `current` is a [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task), and tasks don't have a `IsCommandExecution` method AFAIK.

Comment: It's an extension method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You should never use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html). This goes double on ASP.NET, since constructed tasks are always Delegate Tasks, which [interfere with the ASP.NET usage of the thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net). The actual reason that the `await` hangs is because [manually-created tasks need to be started](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html).

If you have synchronous work that you need to wrap into a `Task` to work alongside asynchronous tasks, then you should use `Task.CompletedTask` and `Task.FromException`:

```
private static Task SynchronousWork(Func<IEnumerable<IExecutionResult>, TOutput> outputBuilder)
{
  try { _output = outputBuilder(_results); return Task.CompletedTask; }
  catch (Exception ex) { return Task.FromException(ex); }
}

public IPipeBuilder<TOutput> Returns(Func<IEnumerable<IExecutionResult>, TOutput> outputBuilder)
{
  _pipe.Enqueue(SynchronousWork(outputBuilder));
  return this;
}
```

However, note that this executes `outputBuilder` *immediately*, which may not be desirable due to its side effects on `_results` and `_output`. If you want a *delayed execution queue*, then the type in the queue needs to be changed from `Task` to `Func<Task>`. Then you can add to it as such:

```
public IPipeBuilder<TOutput> Returns(Func<IEnumerable<IExecutionResult>, TOutput> outputBuilder)
{
  _pipe.Enqueue(() =>
  {
    try { _output = outputBuilder(_results); return Task.CompletedTask; }
    catch (Exception ex) { return Task.FromException(ex); }
  });

  return this;
}
```

and you would consume it by calling each delegate one at a time and inspecting the task it returns:

```
public async Task<TOutput> Execute()
{
  while (_pipe.TryDequeue(out var currentFunc))
  {
    var currentTask = currentFunc();
    if (currentTask.IsCommandExecution())
    {
      IExecutionResult result = await (Task<IExecutionResult>)currentTask;
      _results.Add(result);
    }
    else
    {
      await currentTask;
    }
  }

  return _output;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch, i must have looked at this 20 times, and didn't see it

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thank you. I've ended up with such class and `Queue<Func<Task>>` like you said.

```cs
public sealed class SyncTaskWrapper
{
    private Func<Task> _action;

    public SyncTaskWrapper(Action action)
        => _action = CreateFunc(action);

    private static Func<Task> CreateFunc(Action action)
        => () =>
        {
            try
            {
                action();

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return Task.FromException(exception);
            }
        };

    public static implicit operator Func<Task>(SyncTaskWrapper @this)
        => @this._action;
}
```

with usage

```cs
_pipe.Enqueue(new SyncTaskWrapper(() =>
    _output = outputBuilder(_results)));
```